# At the ..... level/ on the ..... level

Tags: prepositions

Would any of you be able to advise me which sentence could be correct? I am a bit confused.

1. Administrative support **at** the Project Management level?
2. Administrative support **on** the Project Management level?

Project Management is a Business Unit/ Department in this sentence.

Comment: If you could provide slightly more context, that would help; otherwise they *could* both work.

Comment: "On the level" is an English idiom that means "honest". This introduces some false information scent into the title. I suggest renaming it, "on the ___ level".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context; if the context is one of possible administrative support at different levels, then to make that clear in your enunciation you use "at". On the other hand, if the context is not one that includes that notion you use "on".

An examination of the usage for "at" and "on" from the following ngrams will show, however, that it is difficult to make the difference ([at](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+the+*+level&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cat%20the%20%2A%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bat%20the%20same%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20local%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20national%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20highest%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20state%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20.05%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20federal%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20lowest%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20international%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20molecular%20level%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cat%20the%20*%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bat%20the%20same%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20local%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20national%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20highest%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20state%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20.05%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20federal%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20lowest%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20international%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20molecular%20level%3B%2Cc0), [on](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+*+level&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Con%20the%20%2A%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20same%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20local%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20national%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20lower%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20highest%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20ground%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20state%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20college%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20price%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20upper%20level%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Con%20the%20*%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20same%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20local%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20national%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20lower%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20highest%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20ground%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20state%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20college%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20price%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20upper%20level%3B%2Cc0)) .
This can be seen also from this next comparison: [at the national level](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+the+national+level&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20national%20level%3B%2Cc0), [on the national level](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+national+level&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20national%20level%3B%2Cc0).